# Trouble downloading pandarallel

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pandarallel

I'm trying to download pandarallel but it's not working, this is the code I'm using in terminal:

```
pip install pandarallel [--upgrade] [--user]`
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Parse error at "'[--upgra'": Expected string_end
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
pip install pandarallel
```

If you want to upgrade the package already installed:

```
pip install pandarallel --upgrade
```

If you want to install the package in your user's python directory:

```
pip install pandarallel --user
```

A combination of two:

```
pip install pandarallel --upgrade --user
```

The `[...]` means it's an option.